# Symmetries of double dual of Riemann curvature tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, symmetry, tensor-calculus, curvature

The definition of the double dual of Riemann is as follows:
$$G^{\alpha\beta}{}{}_{\gamma\delta} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}R^{\rho\sigma}{}{}_{\mu\nu}\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\rho\sigma\gamma\delta} $$

Now my question is how to prove that this tensor satisfy: $G^{\alpha}{}_{[\beta\gamma\delta]} = 0$

Comment: The double Hodge dual of Riemann has the same symmetries as the Riemann curvature tensor.

Comment: I know that it has the same symmetries, I am asking for a proof.

Comment: Since the Hodge dual is an operator on differential forms, I would have used Cartan's differential forms. For instance, the Riemann curvature tensor would become a differential $2$-form with $(1,1)$ tensor components: $(R^{\alpha}_{\;\;\beta})_{\gamma\delta}dx^\gamma \wedge dx^\delta$. Similarly for $G$. The proofs simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, I use the Latin letters, and I rewrite the double dual of Riemann tensor as
$$
G_{abcd} = \frac{1}{4} \epsilon_{ab}{}^{ef} \, R_{efgh} \, \epsilon_{cd}{}^{gh} .
$$
Now, we want to see whether $G_{a [bcd]} = 0$. To do so, we calculate
$$
G_{abcd} + G_{acdb} + G_{adbc} = \frac{1}{4}  \left( \epsilon_{ab}{}^{ef} \epsilon_{cd}{}^{gh} + \epsilon_{ac}{}^{ef} \epsilon_{db}{}^{gh} + \epsilon_{ad}{}^{ef} \epsilon_{bc}{}^{gh} \right)R_{efgh}
\,.
$$
Using the property of the Levi-Civita tensor; i.e., 
$$
\epsilon_{ab}{}^{ef} \epsilon_{cd}{}^{gh}
=
(-1)^q \delta^{efgh}_{abcd} \,,
$$
where $q$ is the number of negatives in the metric signature (in GR this is equal to one) and $\delta^{efgh}_{abcd} := 4! \delta^{efgh}_{[abcd]}$ is the generalised Kronecker delta, we obtain
\begin{equation}
 G_{abcd} + G_{acdb} + G_{adbc} =
-\frac{1}{4} \left( \delta^{efgh}_{abcd} + \delta^{efgh}_{acdb} + \delta^{efgh}_{a dbc} \right) R_{efgh} . \tag{1}
\end{equation}
The expression in the bracket is a cyclic (symmetric)  permutation within a totally anti-symmetric (the generalised Kronecker delta) tensor, i.e., $\delta^{efgh}_{[a(bcd)]}$. But, this vanishes as you may show this by explicit calculation!

**Alternatively:**
One could use the definition of a totally antisymmetric tensor given by the generalised Kronecker delta. For a tensor $T_{abcd}$ one has
$$
 T_{[abcd]} = \frac{1}{4!} \delta^{efgh}_{abcd} \, T_{efgh}.
$$
Then, the equation (1) becomes:
$$
G_{abcd} + G_{acdb} + G_{adbc}
=
- 3! \left( R_{[abcd]} + R_{[acdb]} + R_{[adbc]} \right).
$$
This obviously vanishes. To show the result one can expand the expressions and use the algebraic symmetries of Riemann tensor.

Comment: By explicit calculation you mean by plugging in numbers for abcd? And if so way not doing it from the start? And is there a smarter way to do it without explicit calculation?

Comment: No! I don't mean that. I mean you could expand the symmetry and anti symmetry brackets in the generalized Kronecker delta, if you don't accept that the expression in the last line vanishes.

Comment: I understood why it is 0, but the symmetry bracket of 3 indices has 6 terms not 3 therefore why the expression in the bracket is the symmetry brackets of the generalized Kronecker delta?

Comment: No! Note that the symmetry parentheses for three indices is defined by: $T_{(abc)} := \frac{1}{3!} (T_{abc} + T_{bca} + T_{cab} + T_{bac} + T_{ acb} + T_{cba} ) $.

Comment: And how does it equal to the expression in the bracket?  3 terms are missing

Comment: Use the property of the Kronecker delta. If you still have problem, I will add another explicit calculation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107464/discussion-between-joe-and-astrolabe).